# jquerytypeahead from runningcoder.org : Id instead of Name in POST value

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead

When I send the from I get the value **$_POST['person_id'] = "John Smith"**. 
But I need the Id, not the name. I need: **$_POST['person_id'] = 1**.

HTML:

```
<form id="form-person" name="form-person" method="post" action="personchoose">
    <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
            <div class="typeahead__query">
                <input class="person_id" name="person_id" 
                       placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" type="search">
            </div>
            <div class="typeahead__button">
                <button type="submit">
                    <i class="typeahead__search-icon"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.typeahead({
        input: ".person_id",
        order: "desc", 
        source: [{id:1, display:"John Smith"},{id:2, display:"Simen Nguien"},{id:3, display:"Maria Carlata"},{id:4, display:"Anna Sngenta"},{id:5, display:"Carmen Muller"}]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the typeahead plugin is to pre-populate the text box before form submission.  Therefore, the only value that is being submitted is the persons name in the textbox value.

There are many ways to achieve what you want but probably the easiest is to use the callback functions of the plugin. Either when someone clicks/selects the option or submits the form.

First add a hidden field to the form for the id of the person to be stored:

```
<form id="form-person" name="form-person" method="post" action="personchoose">
    <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
            <div class="typeahead__query">
                <input class="person_id" name="person_name" 
                       placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" type="search">
              <input type="hidden" name="person_id" id="person_id" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="typeahead__button">
                <button type="submit"> submit
                    <i class="typeahead__search-icon"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Then use the callbacks to set the hidden field with the selected item:

```
$.typeahead({
        input: ".person_id",
        order: "desc", 
        source: [{id:1, display:"John Smith"},{id:2, display:"Simen Nguien"},{id:3, display:"Maria Carlata"},{id:4, display:"Anna Sngenta"},{id:5, display:"Carmen Muller"}],
  callback: {
        onClick: function (node, a, item, event) {
          $('#person_id').val(item.id);
        },
      onSubmit: function() {
        console.log($('#person_id').val());
      }
    }
    });
```